# What is the plural form of boxing (as in box/package)?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

What is the plural form of the word "boxing"? In meaning box/package **noun**. Is "boxings" the correct form in that case? Perhaps it's not, because it's a gerund and not an exception.

Or should we simply regard it as a noun that may be plural, similar to drawings, writings, listings and imaginings, for example?

“The boxings of gifts from our patisserie are varied and impressive.” is a concise and understandable usage of “boxings”.

Comment: where did you see "boxing" used as a noun to mean "packaging"? As a native AmE speaker, I have never seen or heard that construction before.

Comment: M-W certainly gives what looks like a count usage ('an act of putting in a box'), but the plural form is very rare (exceedingly so in this sense) on the internet. I'd say that this particular ing-form hasn't fully converted to a deverbal noun. As yet.

Comment: Welcome! To make this question answerable, please edit to explain a bit more about what you mean. "Boxing" can refer to the act of putting something in a box, but it would be odd to pluralize that meaning. "Packaging" can refer to a box or other material, but strangely, "boxing" isn't used that way, and it's usually a noncount noun anyway.

Comment: im non-native speaker and the word was introduced by my colleagues in our documentation. It is propably not appropriate word for describing package, but google(translate and some dictionaries) says it's possible for singular form. @Esther

Comment: A not entirely implausible scenario: "Have you seen those unboxing videos? Somebody has to be doing a lot of boxing first to set up those videos." 'Boxings' is unnatural. I think ;'boxing' is best as a mass noun.

Comment: A good answer could be made here noting that gerunds are mass nouns, but there has been a trend lately of forming plurals out of them eg 'learnings', 'teachings'.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't think *teachings* is at all recent (unless you call 1850 "recent"). [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=teachings&year_start=1750&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Comment: Any kind of action that can be repeated or multiplied can be made into a nonce event _-ing_ noun representing one event, which would have the regular /-Z/ plural if repeated or multiplied. E.g, _the plantings, the grillings, a few drillings,_ etc. It's not normal -- there are nominalizations available for many such verbs -- but it's perfectly grammatical.

Comment: You put one thing in a box, that's one boxing. You put another thing in another box, that's two boxings. Impressive boxings = impressive ways of putting things in a box.  As other commenters have pointed out, native speakers don't normally count boxings, but if they do, it's probably not the wrapping paper or decorations they're referring to - it's possible, but it would more likely be the act itself, of putting something in a box.

Comment: **Boxing was done in warehouse, not the shop**. I would never put an s on that gerund noun. Boxing of pastries can be hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious what I could find in Google books:

*Boxings* appears to be used for *packagings/packaging versions* in the modeling hobby, for example:

> The Sword fabric-winged Hurricane I kit was re-released by AZ Models
> with an injection-moulded canopy in four different **boxings**
> containing a wide variety of different decal options for pre-war and
> wartime fabric-winged Hurricanes operated by Britain, Poland, Finland,
> Yugoslavia and even a captured Italian example plus Polish and
> Czech-flown RAF aircraft. [M. Derry and N. Robinson; *Hawker Hurricane
> and Sea Hurricane*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hawker_Hurricane/QoI7CQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22different%20boxings%22&pg=PA75&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Also typical of Hasegawa was their habit of releasing many different
> **boxings** featuring different markings, the latest of which was released in 2011. [R. Jackson and L. Ritger; *P-51 Mustang*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/P_51_Mustang/jYcIEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22different%20boxings%22&pg=PT207&printsec=frontcover)

> It has already been reissued in at least three different **boxings**
> since then but the kit is unchanged. [R. Jackson; *Mitsubishi A5M
> Zero*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mitsubishi_A6M_Zero/gy8NEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22different%20boxings%22&pg=PT136&printsec=frontcover)

> This kit has been released under several **boxings** with a good selection
> of markings. [B. Green; *Modelling the Messerschmitt Bf 109F and early
> G series*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modelling_the_Messerschmitt_Bf_109F_and/1JijCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22several%20boxings%22&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover)

> It should be mentioned that many of these kits utilise common parts
> and are sometimes **re-boxings** with different markings and
> additional parts. [Dennis Oliver; *Stug III & Stug IV*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stug_III_Stug_IV/xk8IEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kit%20%22boxings%22&pg=PT83&printsec=frontcover)

> Across various **re-boxings**, re-toolings and licensings, Tamiya's
> 911s have demonstrated excellent moulding, detail and design accuracy.
> Currently, vintage Tamiya 1970s' Porsche kits in good condition fetch
> three-figure sums on the market. [Lance Cole; *Porsche 911*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Porsche_911/4ydCEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kit%20%22boxings%22&pg=PA45&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

Answer (score 1):

Consulting my copy of the OED as well as the online version of [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=boxing), I find three relevant meanings for the noun *boxing*:

> 1. Material used for boxes.
> 2. A boxlike covering or enclosure.
> 3. The act of enclosing in a box.

- Source - *American Heritage*

The first is of *material*, something uncountable. Hence, there is **no** plural form.

The second is of *coverings* or *enclosures*. So, it can safely be inferred that the plural form here would be **boxings**.

The third is of an *act*. Accordingly, the plural here again would be **boxings**.